# Infinite scrollbar in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I am writing a book viewer that dynamically loads content as the user scrolls down to it. The first problem I'm having is how to set up the scrollbar. Since we only store paragraphs in our database with no size information, I can only guess how long the document is. Based upon such a guess, I may want to create a scrollable window that appears 10,000 pixels long and loads paragraphs as needed.

The simplest way I can think is to actually create a DIV that is 10,000 pixels long and absolutely position an embedded div at the scroll position showing my content.

Is there a way to totally control the scrollbar under Javascript (setting its min, max, position, relative thumb size) or do I go the simple way mentioned above or is there another way to do this?

I am using ExtJS framework but it does not seem to offer any direct help there, though V4 does include an infinite grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers to this question simply extended the content as the user reached the bottom, this is not what I was after. I need to display a fully sized, but sparsely populated, scrollable region. The solution I came up with was pretty simple:

I created a scrollable DIV (call it book) with a set of inner DIVs for each paragraph in the book. I need to do it by paragraph as this has special meaning in our application, otherwise, you'd probably do it by page. The paragraph DIVs have a default size based upon a guess of how big they are.

When the book DIV is scrolled, the javascript calculates which paragraph DIVs are now visible. Those that are visible but are not populated are bundled together. A web service is then used to populate the required paragraph DIVs and accurately size them.

The algorithm I use bundles some surrounding (not not-visible) paragraphs to give some read ahead and chunking efficiencies. A lazy loader reads further paragraphs once the screen has been updated to further aid smooth scrolling.

This turned out too be very simple. The hard work is in the chunking algorithms and adding a lazy reader.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a number of ways:

**Masonry Infinite Scroll**  http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/infinite-scroll.html

Cpde Sample:

```
$wall.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page_nav',  // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loadingImg : 'img/loader.gif',
  donetext  : 'No more pages to load.',
  debug: false,
  errorCallback: function() { 
    // fade out the error message after 2 seconds
    $('#infscr-loading').animate({opacity: .8},2000).fadeOut('normal');   
  }
  },
  // call masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) { 
    $(this).masonry({ appendedContent: $( newElements ) }); 
  }
);
```

**AJAXian Way (No Plugin)** http://ajaxian.com/archives/implementing-infinite-scrolling-with-jquery

Code:

```
//Scroll Detection
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           lastPostFunc();
        }
});

//Loading More content
function lastPostFunc()
{
    $(â€™div#lastPostsLoaderâ€™).html(â€™<img src="bigLoader.gif"/>â€™);
    $.post("scroll.asp?action=getLastPosts&lastID=" + $(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id"),   

    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
        $(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);           
        }
        $(â€™div#lastPostsLoaderâ€™).empty();
    });
};
```

**Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin (Originally WordPress Plugin)** http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Sample Code:

```
// infinitescroll() is called on the element that surrounds 
// the items you will be loading more of
  $('#content').infinitescroll({

    navSelector  : "div.navigation",            
                   // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",    
                   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : "#content div.post"          
                   // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  });
All options


// usage:
// $(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback]);

// infinitescroll() is called on the element that surrounds 
// the items you will be loading more of
$('#content').infinitescroll({

  navSelector  : "div.navigation",            
                 // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)

  nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",    
                 // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)

  itemSelector : "#content div.post",          
                 // selector for all items you'll retrieve

  debug        : true,                        
                 // enable debug messaging ( to console.log )

  loadingImg   : "/img/loading.gif",          
                 // loading image.
                 // default: "http://www.infinite-scroll.com/loading.gif"

  loadingText  : "Loading new posts...",      
                 // text accompanying loading image
                 // default: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>"

  animate      : true,      
                 // boolean, if the page will do an animated scroll when new content loads
                 // default: false

  extraScrollPx: 50,      
                 // number of additonal pixels that the page will scroll 
                 // (in addition to the height of the loading div)
                 // animate must be true for this to matter
                 // default: 150

  donetext     : "I think we've hit the end, Jim" ,
                 // text displayed when all items have been retrieved
                 // default: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>"

  bufferPx     : 40,
                 // increase this number if you want infscroll to fire quicker
                 // (a high number means a user will not see the loading message)
                 // new in 1.2
                 // default: 40

  errorCallback: function(){},
                 // called when a requested page 404's or when there is no more content
                 // new in 1.2                   

  localMode    : true
                 // enable an overflow:auto box to have the same functionality
                 // demo: http://paulirish.com/demo/infscr
                 // instead of watching the entire window scrolling the element this plugin
                 //   was called on will be watched
                 // new in 1.2
                 // default: false


    },function(arrayOfNewElems){

     // optional callback when new content is successfully loaded in.

     // keyword `this` will refer to the new DOM content that was just added.
     // as of 1.5, `this` matches the element you called the plugin on (e.g. #content)
     //                   all the new elements that were found are passed in as an array

});

// load all post divs from page 2 into an off-DOM div
$('<div/>').load('/page/2/ #content div.post',function(){ 
    $(this).appendTo('#content');    // once they're loaded, append them to our content area
});
```

**Load Content While Scrolling With jQuery (Another No PLugin Sample)** http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

Code:

```
function lastPostFunc() 
{ 
    $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
    $.post("scroll.asp?action=getLastPosts&lastID=" + $(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id"),     

    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
        $(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);            
        }
        $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
    });
}; 

$(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           lastPostFunc();
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for those. Unfortunately, all of them simply extend the page when the user scrolls to the bottom. That is fine for a blog viewer where people are likely to read them sequentially. Look at the scrollbar as you hit the bottom - you hit the 100% mark, then page extends and you are now at the 90% mark. My app is a book viewer, I think users will expect to be able to drag the scroll thumb anywhere in the book. Furthermore, my books can be thousands of pages long - thus I need to swap-out pages not visible.

Comment: I think you'll need to use plain-old-frameset, or maybe (more likely?) iframe for this. I think this is how Google Reader does it by having infinite scroll for posts on wide right side and separating the list of blogs on the narrow left side non-moved.

Comment: Have you tried the iframes stuff with this kind of script on the scrollable iframe ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this infinite scroller I found on Smashing Magazine this morning:

http://markholton.com/posts/17-infiniscroll-jquery-plugin-released

Comment: Thanks. As I commented to Mohamed Meligy below: Unfortunately, this simply extends the page when the user scrolls to the bottom. That is fine for a blog viewer where people are likely to read them sequentially. Look at the scrollbar as you hit the bottom - you hit the 100% mark, then page extends and you are now at the 90% mark. My app is a book viewer, I think users will expect to be able to drag the scroll thumb anywhere in the book. Furthermore, my books can be thousands of pages long - thus I need to swap-out pages not visible.