# Laravel 5 : how to create horizontal infinite scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, frontend

I would like to display a list of eloquent objects with pagination. Each page has a table of 6 objects each of which is displayed in div elements of the card class of bootstrap 4 such that the objects are arranged like the follows in each page.

obj1 | obj2 | obj3

obj4 | obj5 | obj6

Which JS plugin can help?
Any code example of the frontend is welcomed.

Comment: Friend, you have some answers on stackoverflow e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136694/infinite-scrollbar-in-javascript Your question requiring a suggestion would most likely attract opinionated answers which does not fit Stackoverlow's expected way to ask questions. Please check for example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infinite+scroll+bootstrap

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried my very best to make my question specific. Which part isn't specfic enough? Especially I am using Laravel, the front end implementation might be different from the vanilla way. What make it even more tricky is that it is HORIZONTAL. Still struggling.

Comment: This looks promising:  https://shareurcodes.com/blog/create-infinite-scroll-with-filters-in-laravel-using-vuejs